# Remove an active class by clicking on a parent's brother item in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a get a card script, that consists of 2 phases.
Selecting a card > opens a relevant window on the right
Pressing an Apply now button on that opened window > opens a relevant window on the bottom.

Right now everything works as intended, except:
I want to make so that if a person removes a card selection (.gacca1 / .gacca2), it also removes the "activated" class from the "Get card" div (.gaccaiGET), thus removing the bottom div (.gara). Right now, it keeps the "Get a card" activated, even if you deactivate the card selector.

No matter how I try (with my beginner js skills), i can't make it work.

Also, if you look at the html and css, you will see that most of the elements are positioned absolute, which is a very bad way of making this work. Unfortunately, I could not figure a way to make the positions relative, because the

```
.divclass.active + .otherdivclass { css }
```

works only for brother elements, and, even, only for the brother elements that are next to each other. Which resulted in writing poor html and css, to make it look and work the way I want it to. If you have any tips on this matter, please let me know!

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/4XM9A/10/

```
(function () {
    var links = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.gacca1'));
    var links2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.gacca2'));
    var links3 = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.gaccaiGET'));

    var toggleClass = function (className, element) {
        element.classList.toggle(className);
    };

    var clickHandler = function (linksToDisable) {
        return function () {
            toggleClass('active', this);
            linksToDisable.filter(function (link) {
                return link.classList.contains('active');
            })
            .forEach(function (link) {
                toggleClass('active', link);
            });

        };
    };

    links.forEach(function (link) {
        link.addEventListener('click', clickHandler(links2));
    });
    links2.forEach(function (link) {
        link.addEventListener('click', clickHandler(links));
    });
    links3.forEach(function (link) {
        link.addEventListener('click', function () {
            toggleClass('active', this);
        });
    });
}());
```

Comment: ***most of the elements are positioned absolute*** in fact absolute positioning is a friend of CSS selector, in some case normally CSS selector can't select an element, but if you swap the elements and use absolute positioning to position them, CSS selector will work.

Comment: I don't figure out what's the problem here, the demo seems to be fine, selecting an item on the left will show the button Get card... clicking it again will hide that button. Is that not what you want?

Comment: So, you don't see a problem with the css and html? Good to know! As for the Javascript problem, I meant that once you click on the "Get a Card" button in the opened window - it opens another window. That window doesn't close again once you remove the card selection.
CARD > CARD WINDOW > GET A CARD WINDOW. When you close "CARD WINDOW", the "GET A CARD WINDOW" should automatically close too, and when you open that same "CARD" again, it should not display the previously opened "GET A CARD WINDOW". I hope I explained good enough.

Comment: I don't see any visible windows that are opened or closed, all the so-called windows ***are shown initially***, I've not looked into the HTML code, but to make it clearer we must know how a window is opened/closed. And maybe how a window looks? they all look like normal elements with border (and as I said they are shown intially, no waiting for you to click or select something).

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/DsrY1I02L7W
As I have shown here - you click 1 > opens 1. Click 2 > opens 2. When you click 2 again - closes 2. When you click 1 again - closes 1.
BUT, if you click 1 > opens 1, click 2 > opens 2, and then click 1 again - it closes 1, and if you click 1 again - it opens 1 with the already open 2.
I am trying to do so that, when you close 1, it automatically closes 2 inside, so that when you click 1 again, 2 is not automatically open, because it was already activated before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you should firstly toggle '.active' of all divs of the '.gaccai' that goes after the ".active" parent. Try changing function toggleClass a bit:

```
var toggleClass = function (className, element) {
        var array = document.querySelectorAll('.' + element.classList + ' + .gaccai .active');
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i].classList.toggle(className);
        }
        element.classList.toggle(className);
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, that works quite good! It looks quite weird, especially with the i++, but I guess, i will understand it later in my journey.